# Typing Russell's "Sur la Logique des Relations"

Tags: tables, math-mode

I'm having some trouble typing Russell's definitions in TexWorks, mainly because of the spaces and numerations of propositions. Anyway, my output it's a complete disaster. How could I maintain the symbols in line and between the numeration correctly?
[image: Third page of Russell's "Sur la Logique des Relations"]

Have a nice day

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: This is why Knuth invented TeX.

Comment: You may find it instructive to see how others have typset such works:  see http://people.umass.edu/klement/#editions or the TeX editions of Russell and others at http://www.gutenberg.org/

Comment: this looks like an interesting problem.  please give the full reference for the work in which this appears -- i would like to get a copy from the library to look at it more carefully, since i don't understand the logic of the layout from this small sample.  (looking at the content, i would have done some things differently, but one assumes that the author approved this before publication.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton this article is about the logic of relations which Russell developed in the beginning of the XX century. It's an aprimoration to Peirce's. You will find this article very interesting, since he defines numbers, fractions, negative numbers, etc. all based on his logic. Unfortunately, his notation is more difficult, so I also send a link of Whitehead's paper who treats the same subject, and explains the notations used. I hope you enjoy, have a nice day.
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2370026
https://archive.org/stream/rivistadimatema00peangoog#page/n127/mode/2up

Comment: http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/ may have something helpful. Since you've not given us an MWE, it is hard to suggest anything terribly specific.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look. I didn't provide any sample because the code was very messy. As I say the output was so horrible, so I excluded it. I'm just trying to type the first line, that's all, and my inexperience in latex makes it a lot more difficult.